# sql serveur query update cascade

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, cascade

I need to change an the id of 1 table. but the id is use on other tables. So how to create a sql query for update every table at the same time?

```
UPDATE table1,table2,table3
SET id = 2
where id=1
```

How create an update cascade query?

Comment: An UPDATE statement can only affect one table at a time. You could temporarily drop the constraints, update the three tables, then re-enable the constraints; or you could add a new row to the parent table, copy the rest of the data from the old row, update the other tables that point to it, and then delete the old row.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? I'm assuming (because of your code snippet) that these are surrogate keys so why would you ever want to change them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your foreign keys with [`ON UPDATE CASCADE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can simply update the primary key and all the references will change automatically.